# Remove Glyph at End of Truncated Lines

Tags: emacs, terminal

When using Emacs 23 in a terminal with truncate-lines enabled Emacs adds a dollar sign to the end of each line, indicating the text continues past the edge of the screen. This bothers me and I would like to disable this feature or somehow hide the dollar sign. Is this possible? If so how would it be done?

[image: Glyph at end of truncated line.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with this:

```
 (set-display-table-slot standard-display-table 0 ?\ )
```

Comment: That's strange. How did you try it?

Comment: It doesn't work for me, either (in the GUI)... but it does register a value of `32` in the 6th last entry in `standard-display-table` .. I"ve evaluated it via `C-x C-e`, and by putting it in my `.emacs` .. but with no effec on-screen either way.

Comment: Well, if some extension is creating its own per-window or per-buffer display table, then you'll probably need to hook the modification somewhere, and it gets much more complicated...

Answer (score -1):

I think that's because `whitespace-mode` is activated, so you can
either desactivated it with
<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>`whitespace-mode`<kbd>RET</kbd> or customize
what should be displayed and how with
<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>`customize-group`<kbd>RET</kbd>`whitespace`<kbd>RET</kbd> and <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd>`customize-group`<kbd>RET</kbd>`whitespace-faces`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: This is actually different I think. The glyph I want to remove is not the newline mark from whitespace-mode, it is a glyph that comes from truncate-lines that indicates there is text to right or left of the visible screen area. I've already customized whitespace-mode to show a pilcrow for a new line character. Here is the Emacs manual page for truncate-lines where this dollar sign glyph is briefly mentioned. http://www.gnu.org/s/libtool/manual/emacs/Line-Truncation.html#Line-Truncation

Comment: Oops you're right, it's because of `truncate-lines`, so you can either
desactivate it with
M-x `toggle-truncate-lines` RET and
instead of a '$' at the end the line the line will just continue
bellow, or you can enable `world-wrap` with
M-x `toggle-truncate-lines` RET.