# Copy long URL (minus "\" chars) from emacs?

Tags: emacs

I often receive emails containing extremely long (>= 300 characters)
URLs that I'd like to click on. This does not work properly because emacs flows the text onto multiple lines on the terminal and appends a "\" character at the end of each of these virtual lines to indicate continuation. The normal mouse-select and ctrl-left-click method doesn't work properly because the "\" characters are included and invalidate the URL.

I use emacs in -nw (terminal) mode.

Is there a way to change my OS's (Linux Mint 15) or emacs' behavior so that the entire URL is selected instead of just the first virtual line?

The workaround I've been using is to mouse-select the entire URL, including the "\" characters, copy, paste into the browser, then delete the "\" characters by hand.

The other thing I do, if the URL is less than about 250 characters is stretch the terminal window wide enough to contain the entire URL on a single line.

Comment: Check out this answer by one of the Emacs maintainers:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003230/getting-rid-of-backslash-at-the-end-of-wrapped-lines-for-copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with `browse-url`. I still see the continuation chars, but it works. And don't forget to set

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-firefox)
```

### UPD

If you connect with `ssh -X`, you can use `xclip`.
This [elisp code](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/xclip.el) wraps around `xclip`
and makes it so that after `turn-on-xclip` everything you kill or copy with
the usual commands will be also sent to xclip.

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't seem to work for me because my emacs session is through SSH to a remote computer, so when I use browse-url emacs cannot invoke the browser (firefox) since it doesn't exist on the machine running emacs.